# How to write proxy program for resending packets?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, proxy

I need to write program using raw sockets in c language on proxy server between two hosts.
I've written some code for it (and set some rules for iptable to change destination address of packets to proxy's interfaces), where I am receiving packet, print data in this packet and then send the packet to receiver.

It's working on my simple client/server programs on raw sockets, but when I am trying to establish a connection through a proxy - it doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas on how I can write this program without using the kernel?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

#define PCKT_LEN 8192

int main(void){
  int s;
  char buffer[PCKT_LEN];
  struct sockaddr saddr;
  struct sockaddr_in daddr;
  memset(buffer, 0, PCKT_LEN);

  s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if(s < 0){
     printf("socket() error");
     return -1;
  }

  int saddr_size = sizeof(saddr);
  int header_size = sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr);
  unsigned int count;

  daddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  daddr.sin_port = htons(1234);
  daddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("2.2.2.1");

  while(1){
    if(recvfrom(s, buffer, PCKT_LEN , 0, &saddr, &saddr_size) < 0){
       printf("recvfrom() error");
       return -1;
    }
    else{
        int i = header_size;
        for(; i < PCKT_LEN; i++)
            printf("%c", buffer[i]);

      if (sendto (s, buffer, PCKT_LEN, 0, &daddr, &saddr_size) < 0)
        printf("sendto() error");
        return -1;
      }
    }
  }
  close(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "establishing connection through a proxy"? Are you trying to transparently enforce a proxy through your code, or is the client already proxy-aware?

Comment: I am trying to transparently enforce a proxy through code

Comment: You can't implement transparent proxy by just redirecting packets. With HTTPs you need to retain the original IP and establish CONNECT tunnel; you also need to use full instead of relative URLs etc. etc.
This is a very wide question.

Answer (score 1):

(Your code has serious bugs. For example, the last argument to `sendto(2)` should not be a pointer. I'll assume it's not the real code and that the real code compiles without warnings.)

With the nagging out of the way, I think one problem is that you're accidentally including an extra IP header in the packets you send. `raw(7)` has the following:

> The IPv4 layer generates an IP header when sending a packet unless the `IP_HDRINCL` socket option is enabled on the socket.  When it is enabled, the packet must contain an IP header. For receiving the IP header is always included in the packet.

`IP_HDRINCL` is not enabled by default unless `protocol` is `IPPROTO_RAW` (see a bit further down in `raw(7)`), meaning it's disabled in your case. (I also checked with `getsockopt(2)`.)

You will have to either enable `IP_HDRINCL` using `setsockopt(2)` to tell the kernel that you're supplying the header yourself, or not include the header in `sendto()`.

It's better to look at the [*IHL*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#IHL) field in the IP header than assume it has fixed size by the way. The IP header could include options.

There could be other issues as well depending on what you're trying to do, and details might vary for IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are doing I don't think using raw sockets is the way. Those are used for network debugging only.

Fist of all, observe that basically you are copying content from an existing, stabilished connection, rather than tunneling it. You are not doing what is proposed.

If you want to capture connections to a given server:port, for instance, `2.2.2.1:1234`, into your application so that you can tunnel it through a proxy, you can use `iptables`.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 2.2.2.1 --dport 1234 -j REDIRECT
```

Create an application bound to ip `0.0.0.0` listening to TCP port `1234` and every connection attempt to `2.2.2.1:1234` will connect to your application instead, and you can do whatever you please with it.

Comment: and how can I redirect all incoming packets throught one interface, pass it throught my program and send it to server and vice versa? I have client 1.1.1.1 and server 2.2.2.1 and proxy with two interfaces - eth0(1.1.1.2) connected to client and eth1(2.2.2.2) connected to server

Comment: @user3425448 In this case it will be a whole lot more complicated. I know there is software to do that on Windows though, I believe its called Proxify. But you won't be able to tunnel UDP connections using a HTTP Proxy, and theres no proxy that supports all types of traffic. I recommend using a VPN for that matter.